# search and input text for a input box in web site from C# windows form

Tags: c#, html

In my company using a website for Storage Document. Website provided by other company.
I want to write a program with C# for Input text to textbox in that website. text box have name:DocumentName.

like this

```
   <input type="text" class="field" name="DocumentName" value="" id="idDocumentName" placeholder="Search …">
```

Please advice to me What should i do?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking. Also please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Normal, i input something to text box in web site by keyboard. But, in this case, i want to input by software.

Comment: You will need to read about keyboard input simulation in C#, but I don't know if is possible to do what you want, I mean, how are you going to focus websites inputs? Maybe is worth you to think about creating an extension for your browser, I'm not an expert about this btw

Comment: Thanks for your strong support. I think i need consider about other solution.